# How to access a chrome extension's IndexedDB from an external web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension has an IndexedDB as shown in center of the image below.

- How do I get access to the same IndexedDB from a web page (as shown on the right hand side of the image below)?
- Does this require an additional permission in the `manifest.json`?
- Or the use of something like a background page perhaps?

[image: IndexedDB not accessible on web page]

Comment: Do you mean access it from a content script of your extension?

Comment: You need to access indexedDB from a single background page so that you're pulling up stuff from the same database. Quote from MDN: "So while you can access stored data within a domain, you cannot access data across different domains." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB You could accomplish this by adding a persistent background.html page in your manifest.

Comment: @Daniel_L, I think non-persistent event page would be okay as it's autoloaded whenever a message is sent from other parts of the extension. Moreover Chrome discourages persistent background pages.

Comment: @rsanchez - exactly. I need access to the extension's own IndexedDB from the web page. I'll try an event page and see how things go. Thanks.

Comment: @dvdsmpsn Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jkupczak I didn't but I think that having a background page as a proxy to the IndexedDB is likely the way forward -- seems somewhat excessive though.